# Hide or Show Component On Certain Time React Native

Tags: react-native

like the title says, I want to show or hide on a certain time or working time, let's say 8 AM till 4 PM, the button will show on those time, otherwise it will be hidden. how can I achieve that? Thanks

Note: sorry if there is no code because I'm confused on how can I achieve that

Comment: Can't help fully without seeing your code. By using Date() you can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do and it worked,

```
var format = "hh:mm:ss";
var time = Moment(this.props.route.params.timeServer, format),
   beforeTime = Moment(this.props.route.params.time.jam_masuk, format),
   afterTime = Moment(this.props.route.params.time.jam_pulang, format);
if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
   this.setState({ showButton: true });
} else {
   this.setState({ showButton: false });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a condition in your component's return :

```
// above your component's return

const [hours, setHours] = useState(new Date().getHours()); 



// in your component's return (<Button /> is a react an element from react-native-elements) :

{hours > 8 && hours < 16 ? <Button title='Show me between 8AM and 4PM'/>}
```